# How do I transform table data in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have fetched data from JIRA to my PowerBi in below table format.

```
Project Component Received date Response date Complete date Criteria
Alpha   Plan        1/2/2024    2/2/2024        16/4/2024   Met
Alpha   Strategy    1/2/2017    2/2/2018        03/4/2022   Met
Bravo   Sow         1/2/2024    2/2/2024        21/4/2024   Not Met
Bravo   Plan        1/2/2024    2/4/2024        13/6/2024   Met
Charlie Plan        1/2/2024    2/2/2024        30/4/2024   Met
Charlie TCR         1/2/2015    2/2/2017        15/4/2024   Not Met
```

I would like to transform the above data in below table format but not sure how to do it.

```
Project    PlanReceivedDate  Plan Response Date  PlanCompleteDate Plan Criteria StrategyReceivedDate  StrategyResponseDate  StrategyCompleteDate StrategyCriteria SowReceivedDate  SowResponseDate SowCompleteDate SowCriteria TCRreceivedDate TCRResponseDate TCRCompleteDate TCRCriteria
Alpha      01/02/2024        02/02/2024          03/04/2024       Met           01/02/2017            02/02/2018            03/04/2022           Met
Bravo      01/02/2024        02/04/2024          13/06/2024       Met                                                                                             01/02/2024       02/02/2024      21/04/2024      Not Met
Charlie    01/02/2024        02/02/2024          30/04/2024       Met                                                                                                                                                           01/02/2015      02/02/2017      15/04/2024     Not Met
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you get your output ?

Comment: hi @AmiraBedhiafi , that is my question, I want this output.

Comment: Yes but what are the rules ? The logic behind ?

Comment: Rules - 1 Each project can be used once per row. 2. Component is unique for each project and moved to column for each component type.

Comment: It is not clear can you precise more ?